# APA style in German, but with commas (except for in the text)

Tags: apa-style, apa6, german

I'm looking for some help. I'm writing my master's thesis in German using the APA style (apacite package). So since the document is in German it automatically deletes the commas in the reference list and the in-text citations. Theoretically this would be right, but I'm told to do the citations APA style including the commas. 
I already found out how I can re-establish the commas, redefining the BCBL and BCBT commands.  It works fine, but now in the in-text citations, I also get the commas, which is wrong in German. So for example Solymosi, Bowers, und Fujiyama (2015) should be Solymosi, Bowers und Fujiyama (2015) in the text. Is there any way to delete this comma? So I only need this change to happen, when I'm not citing in parentheses.

Thank you!
Anita

Here's what I've done

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,DIV=10,bibliography=totoc,listof=totoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}
\renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}
```

Edit:
Here's the bibentry

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Diplomarbeit}
```

And here's an example

```
Nach \cite{Cozens2002CriminogenicDesigns} gibt es Orte, an denen  Menschen sich mehr vor eventuellen Verbrechen fürchten als an anderen. Kriminalitätsfurcht ist zum Beispiel höher, wenn Vegetation die Sicht versperrt \citep{Kuo1998TransformingPreference}.
```

It then looks like this: 
[image: Example]

So the red comma shouldn't be there, but the green commas should.

And here are the bibentries for \cite{Cozens2002CriminogenicDesigns} and \citep{Kuo1998TransformingPreference}. Basically \citep works fine and \cite should be changed.

```
@article{Cozens2002CriminogenicDesigns,
    title = {Criminogenic Associations and Characteristic British Housing Designs},
    year = {2002},
    journal = {International Planning Studies},
    author = {Cozens, Paul Michael and Hillier, David and Prescott, Gwyn},
    doi = {10.1080/13563470220132218},
    pages = {119--136},
    volume = {7}
}

@article{Kuo1998TransformingPreference,
    title = {Transforming inner-city landscapes: Trees, sense of safety, and preference},
    year = {1998},
    journal = {Environment and Behavior,},
    author = {Kuo, Frances E. and Bacaicoa, Magdalena and Sullivan, William C.},
    pages = {28--59},
    volume = {30}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please supplement the code with the bib entry and also the part of text with the citation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This probably would be easier to do with `biblatex`. Would you consider using `biblatex-apa`?

Comment: thank you! i edited my entry, i hope it helps :) bernard, would it really be easier using biblatex-apa. what would i have to do?

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the bib entries `Cozens2002CriminogenicDesigns` and `Kuo1998TransformingPreference`?

Comment: Incidentally, the "green" commas just ahead of `&` make the citation call-outs look awful.

Comment: I agree with Mico; the `&` is already horrible, the comma is completely out of place.

Comment: I also would prefer to not have it either, but my professor won't let me submit the thesis without these commas :/

Comment: You usage of the ampersand is definitely wrong in German (it's not allowed to use and ampersand as a substitute for an and except in some very rare cases) and as far as I know State Agency (as for example an Prüfungsamt) have to follow the German spelling standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sympathize with you, who are subject to such dreadful specifications.<sup>1</sup>

Anyway, here's a redefinition of `\BCBL` that should do what you need. Perhaps also `\BCBT` should be treated in the same way, but I don't know where it's used.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{testa,
  author={A. Uthor and W. Riter and P. Laywright},
  title={A paper},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2015,
}
@article{testb,
  author={S. C. I. Entist and W. Riter and P. Laywright},
  title={A paper},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2015,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\protected\def\BCBL{\ifNAT@swa,\fi}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{testa}

\citep{testb}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to make `\BCBL` append a comma only when `&` is to be output, which can be checked by `\ifNAT@swa`. The `\protected` is needed because the macro undergoes full expansion at an unwanted time.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> It is well known that all professors in humanities know the one and the only right citation style, that is, their own.